# Does sketch have the feature of Fireworks - drawing vector items + pixel editing?

Tags: sketch-app, adobe-fireworks

Drawing vecotr+bitmap items in Fireworks is super convenient. However, Adobe had failed to make Fireworks live on and MacOS 64x has sentenced Fireworks to death.

It seems the best alternative is Sketch so I am trying out. However, after some research I found it quite hard to do similar tasks - Where is the pixel tools (for instance, pencil in Fireworks) in Sketch?

Is it even an impossible task? Or do I miss something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.sketch.com/docs/the-interface/#how-to-show-pixels-on-the-canvas

Comment: Thanks Billy, may I know using what tool can I draw one single dot (1x1 pixel) on Sketch?

Comment: I'm not a Sketch user . . . I just looked at the user manual. If you have another question, I suggest you ask a new one.  But as far as I know, Sketch can't do pixel level editing. It's vector based software. Maybe there's a way to switch of anti-aliasing? Or maybe you could make pixel sized squares with a black fill?